# text treated as a column name

Tags: sql-server, delphi

This runs ok on SQL Server 2014 :

```
UPDATE MYTABLE 
SET MYFIELD = MYFIELD + 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'
              + CAST(FOR_DATE AS VARCHAR(30))
```

Porting it to a query in Delphi:

```
 SQL.Text := UPDATE MYTABLE SET MYFIELD = MYFIELD
 + "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"
 + CAST(FOR_DATE AS VARCHAR(30))
```

This throws an error:

> the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog" is treated as a column
>   name (?).

Single quotes arround the text dont work either.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should do the trick, you can use the [`QuotedStr`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.SysUtils.QuotedStr) function to include quotes in a string:

```
SQL.Text := 'UPDATE MYTABLE SET MYFIELD=MYFIELD + ' + 
             QuotedStr('the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog') + 
             '+ CAST(FOR_DATE as varchar(30))';
```

or if you want to include a quote into a string, you need to double it:

```
SQL.Text := 'UPDATE MYTABLE SET MYFIELD=MYFIELD + ' + 
            '''the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog''' + 
            '+ CAST(FOR_DATE as varchar(30))';
```

at last, a better and more secure way is to use parameterized queries, this is the only way to prevent [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection):

```
SQL.Text := 'UPDATE MYTABLE SET MYFIELD = MYFIELD + :MyText'+
            ' + CAST(FOR_DATE AS VARCHAR(30))'; 
ParamByName('MyText').AsString := 'variable text';
```

Comment: You should use a parameterized query instead, let it handle the quotes for you: `SQL.Text := 'UPDATE MYTABLE SET MYFIELD = MYFIELD
 + :MyText + CAST(FOR_DATE AS VARCHAR(30))'; ParamByName('MyText').AsString := 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog';`